# Could not obtain transaction synchronized Session

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

HTTP Status 401 - Authentication Failed: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread.

Does anyone faced this exception when using spring & hibernate.

I used `@EnableTransactionManagement` in configuration. i have `@Transactional` on both service and repository classes. i configured transaction manager. still i have this problem. can some one spot this error

Comment: At what time this happened ? Could provide the complete stacktrace please ?

Comment: At login login. no exceptions printed in the eclipse console. This message comes in browser

Comment: Could you provide your Repository, Service and spring config file please ?

Comment: First of all, you don't need the Transactional annotation decladed in your DAOs, only in your Services which are calling your DAOs. Secondly, can you provide your stacktrace pls?